# Assign line numbers to items in text

Tags: string, vb.net, sorting, for-loop, foreach

I'm quite stuck with a fairly simple task but I'm not entirely sure how to make this function. I have a simple string as seen below:

```
{
"0":{"variable1":"ABC1","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"5":{"variable1":"ABC2","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"3":{"variable1":"BC3","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"1":{"variable1":"DC4","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"4":{"variable1":"DD5","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"}
}
```

What I'm trying to do, in VB.NET, is to create a loop that finds each line and arranges those first numbers "0", "1", etc. in order depending on what line it is on then simply replaces whatever number is in it, with the correct order number.

In simple:

1) Find how many number of lines the string has. Let's say 20 lines for example.

2) Find and replace each number within "": starting point of the lines in order 1-20 for this example.

Output would look like if used the example at the top:

```
{
"2":{"variable1":"ABC1","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"}, //"2" because it is the second line within the string
"3":{"variable1":"ABC2","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"4":{"variable1":"BC3","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"5":{"variable1":"DC4","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"6":{"variable1":"DD5","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"}
}
```

Any ideas for a quick fix?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far, and tell us where that string comes from.

Comment: Somehow you lose the 0 and the 1 and gain a 6.

Comment: The sorted one starts with `2` and not `0` or `1`, why?

Comment: Its not really a sort if it changes the data.  And I am not sure what those are but there are not "simple strings".  The open and closing curlies make it look like something from c# rather than VB.NET

Comment: Yes because it is based on the # of current line. It shows "2" because thats the second line within the string.

Comment: The 2nd line? It looks like the 1st line to me. Is there any line before that then?

Comment: Strings dont have "lines" and it looks like line 0 or 1 not 2.  Very hard to understanding what you want or what that is and even what language you are really dealing with.

Comment: The language is VB.net - that is just a string example from a JSON style script. I'm simply trying to change the starting numbers e.g "2", in order based on the current line it is on.

Comment: Then that isnt a simple string **at all**, but json serialized object data.  Deserialize it. change the data and serialize again is your best bet

Comment: I extract the text as a string within a RichTextBox. I'm currently using a find and replace method but the problem is I have to type in how many lines I want to find and replace for but it could be hundreds. It needs to be in a loop instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question may be a case of "I have X and I need Y" where X is the item which needs attention.

If the string really is as you presented it, then

```
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "{
""0"":{""variable1"":""ABC1"",""variable2"":""AA"",""variable3"":""BB""},
""5"":{""variable1"":""ABC2"",""variable2"":""AA"",""variable3"":""BB""},
""3"":{""variable1"":""BC3"",""variable2"":""AA"",""variable3"":""BB""},
""1"":{""variable1"":""DC4"",""variable2"":""AA"",""variable3"":""BB""},
""4"":{""variable1"":""DD5"",""variable2"":""AA"",""variable3"":""BB""}
}"

        Dim t = s.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        Dim u As New StringBuilder

        For i = 0 To t.Length - 1
            If t(i).StartsWith("""") Then
                Dim parts = t(i).Split({":"c}, 2)
                If parts.Count = 2 Then
                    u.AppendLine($"""{i + 1}"":{parts(1)}")
                End If

            Else
                u.AppendLine(t(i))
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(u.ToString().TrimEnd())

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs:

```
{
"2":{"variable1":"ABC1","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"3":{"variable1":"ABC2","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"4":{"variable1":"BC3","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"5":{"variable1":"DC4","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"},
"6":{"variable1":"DD5","variable2":"AA","variable3":"BB"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to run it but I'm getting a compiler error on line: " u.AppendLine($"""{i + 1}"":{parts(1)}")" - It says $ is an invalid character. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a feature in VS2015. Adjust the line to use string concatenation or `String.Format`.

Comment: Thanks it did go through now however the script simply painted the original string without ordering the numbers based on the # line. Did you mean u.AppendLine(String.Format("""{i + 1}"":{parts(1)}")) like that? It does not seem to edit the string at all, not sure why?

Comment: @user6934446 Something like `u.AppendLine(String.Format("""{0}"":{1}", i + 1, parts(1))`. The output is exactly as you show in your example. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Oh your example is different. I had the code written differently. I'll try this new version this evening. Thank you very much for your help!